# Hide link in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to hide a link to the user so that he can't click it to get to another page but I have several JS scripts and CSS that would take too much work to change so I need the document structure to stay the Same.

How can I achieve that?

This is an example

```
<span>
<a href="xxx">text</a>
</span>
```

I obviously tried to generate this instead

```
<span>text</span>
```

but selectors can't find the text because there's no "a" tag.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Post an actual sample of the real mark-up.

Comment: Omit `href`, or use `href="javascript:void 0"`, or `href="#" onclick="return false;"`.

Comment: you want to hide the url from the user and also dont want that if he clicks should go on other page??

Comment: and by the way, how do you hope to identify that link apart from the other links in the page?

Comment: ok @Robw, it worked perfectly.

Comment: If you want to hide and prevent user from clicking it then WHY you want to put that link there?

Comment: And if you need the document structure to stay the same, why is your example changing the structure/HTML?

Comment: @shanabus because that was an example that broke my system...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable all the links, have such code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
        document.links[i].onclick = function() {
            return false;
        }
    }
};​
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/TdaXd/1/).

This won't change their destination (`href` attribute) just cause that clicking them will have no effect whatsoever.

Comment: I recommend [`document.links`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.links) over `document.getElementsByTagName("a")`, because the first one does not contain anchor elements without `href` attribute.

Comment: @Rob fair enough, I thought of this but wasn't sure it's cross browser. Quick search now told me it's standard so my answer is edited. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Set `style="display: none"` to not display it at all.

Comment: I think that the OP does not mean "hide" in the sense of "not visible", but in the sense of "no effects on click".